# Controller Cleaning. Doctrine in Model

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I want to make my controller thin and to separate business-logic from other operations. For example I have an action:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $languages = $this  ->getEntityManager()
                        ->getRepository('\ApanelLanguage\Entity\LanguageCommon')
                        ->getLanguagesList();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(['languages' => $languages]);
    return $viewModel; 
}
```

but I want to get action like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $model = $new LanguageModel();
    $model->getLanguagesList();
    return $viewModel; 
}
```

Is it possible to do? What must I have in Language/Model/LanguageModel ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the business logic from your controller is a great idea for code reuse and maintainability; however I would recommend against moving the logic to your models. A better solution would be to add a *service layer* to your application.

What is a service layer? [Martin Fowler describes it as the following](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html):

> [A service layer] defines an application's boundary with a layer of services that establishes a set of available operations and coordinates the application's response in each operation.

This essentially means that we add a class in-between your controller and your model.

The great advantage of this approach is that should you need to update the business logic of your application there is no need to update the controller. The controller also becomes unaware of any specific code and therefore can be  reusable in other unrelated projects.

This 'service' could have a simple API, for example:

```
interface ServiceInterface
{
    public function setObjectManager($objectManager);

    public function setRepository($respository);

    public function find($id);

    public function fetchRow($criteria);

    public function fetchAll($criteria);

    public function insert($object);

    public function update($object);

    public function delete($object);
}
```

Then you can implement this interface for your new 'LanguageService'.

```
class LanguageService implements ServiceInterface
{
  // ... all methods from interface

    public function getLanguageList()        
    {
       return $this->repository->getLanguagesList();
    }
}
```

Lastly update your controller to use the new service

```
class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $languageService;

    public function __construct(ServiceInterface $languageService)
    {
        $this->languageService = $languageService;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $languages = $this->languageService->getLanguageList();

        $viewModel = new ViewModel(['languages' => $languages]);

        return $viewModel;
    }

    public function insertAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $service = $this->languageService;

        $form = $service->getInsertForm();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // if our form used the DoctrineObjectHydrator
                // we will get a entity back populated with the
                // form data
                $language = $service->insert($form->getData());

                if ($language instanceof Entity\Language) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    // failure
                }
            }
        }
        //
    }


}
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  However, what about object hydration, filtering and validation processes? For example, controller takes the data from request, service interfaces promotes that an `$object` instance needed as argument (probably entities) to update insert etc. @AlexP, where you would instantiate that objects? I think filtering and validation processes should be completed just before hydration. What about this inputfilter and hydrator dependencies? Is these are dependencies of the related Controller, Service or Repository? I really wonder other/alternative approaches about this point.

Comment: @foozy Great question. You are correct in thinking that the interface would accept a entity (and it possibly should type hint on them too). In ZF2 we can cover this without needing to construct the entity in the controller by having the hydrator return a constructed entity (this is normally the case with the `DoctrineObjectHydrator`) which would then be returned from the form using `$form->getData()`. Also I tend to make the *service* responsible for the forms (we requested the form from the service in the controller, the form is injected into the service from a factory).

Comment: @foozy I added a "insertAction" to explain my comment above.